# Recyclerview need to retain last webview state

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

thing is the first item in my list is logically a header which contains a `WebView` that loads a url of a video and keeps playing the selected video inline as soon as the video item is selected.

But thing is upon scrolling that list further below up to the point where that header item goes out of sight it immediately gets recycled and that webview is now lost and video is now stopped, what i really want is if i can somehow restrict that header item from recycling or i can retain that `ViewHolder`.

I've tried this 
`holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` in `onBindViewHolder()` 
And this 
`listVideos.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 0);` 
but neither of them are working the way i intended, so may be i am wrong about that.

For reference:

```
@Override
public DiscoverPlayerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HEADER) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_discover_header, parent, false);
        HeaderHolder holder = new HeaderHolder(itemView);
        return holder;
    }else {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_discover_video, parent, false);
        return new ItemHolder(itemView);
    }
}
```

So is it possible to achieve this by anyway? as i know the header/footer doesn't recycle in iOS with tableView but since the RecylerView in Android doesn't provide any direct way to set header/footer it's a problem.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there only one video in the whole recyclerview? What are you trying to do is kind of the opposite of what recyclerview is meant for.

Comment: the first item in the recycler view is actually a player layout where video keeps playing inside a webview, rest of the items are the actual videos which user can select to play, Initially that player layout wasn't part of the recyclerview and was a different layout container on top the recyclerview in the xml file, but the requirement got changed now as that player part should also need to be scrollable along with the recyclerview.

Comment: Can maybe this help you out? https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429

Comment: Thanks, i'll check out

Comment: @Soriyyx, that link you have shared is all about playing multiple videos using custom TextureView, which is not related to the question.

Comment: If you have access to the source code of view page in webview you can bind Javascript with Android code. Add a listener to recyclerview to find out when your header view is no longer visible and get playback position of video from javascript. When the header is visible again set that playback position to the player in webview and resume the video.

Comment: Have found an alternate solution to my problem so don't need this right now, but will definitely be looking for in future. With "coordinator layout + putting top layout in the Appbarlayout and list below appbarlayout + setting appropriate scroll flags in Toolbar + tracking the position of the webview on the screen as vertical offset changes in AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener()" I am able to achieve what i wanted.